# How To Avoid Google Play Services Update Required Warning

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm using Google Maps in my Android app and I'm seeing the following message on some older devices:

[image]

I understand the nature of this message and that updating will resolve this issue.

However I would like to avoid users seeing this all together, and just want the map to load on all devices.

Here's what my dependencies look like:

*Please note that I added individual parts of Google Play services that I needed rather than the full library as I started receiving an error from Android Studio about too many lines of code - this was the work around as I just have to many libraries as it seems.*
[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<permission android:name="com.xyzapp.it.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.xyzapp.it.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<!-- Permission to read Google Services -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"  />

<!--Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name=".xyzappitApp"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" android:largeHeap="true" >

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TabHostActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".StatusActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".StatusDetailsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".MyAlertsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".AlertLinesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".AlertDetailsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/ActionBarStyle" />
    <activity android:name=".RouteListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".StopListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".StopTimesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".UpgradeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".TransfersActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".TransfersDetailsActivity" android:theme="@style/MyDialog" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ShareActivity" android:theme="@style/MyDialog" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".ShareDetailsActivity" android:theme="@style/MyDialog" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    <service android:name=".Service.NotificationService" />              

    <receiver android:name="com.xyzapp.it.Receiver.MyAlarmReceiver"  />

    <receiver android:name="com.xyzapp.it.Receiver.ConnectionChangedReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>     

    <receiver android:name="com.xyzapp.it.Receiver.BootCompletedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>


    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"  />

    <meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="123456" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="123456" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />



</application>
```

Ideally I would like to know how to have the map just load and not force the user to update as my minSDK=10 and the app supports Android 2.3 devices and up.

Even if that means targeting a lower version of Google Play services to support SDK 10+ I'm ok with that solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> However I would like to avoid users seeing this all together, and just want the map to load on all devices.

Then don't use Maps V2. Instead, use some other mapping solution (e.g., Open Street Map).

Otherwise, there is no "magic" dependency that will avoid this dialog on all devices. While you are welcome to use some older version of that `play-services-maps` dependency, there is no guarantee that ~1.5 billion devices will all support that particular version of the Play Services engine without any updates.

Comment: I'm only looking to target devices that are Android 2.3 and up.

Comment: @AlexVPerl: That does not change anything from my answer. Android OS version has nothing much to do with Play Services version. Moreover, that is ~99.7% of Android devices accessing the Play Store, based on [the May 2015 dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: Thanks I get that part. Can I include a lower version of the PlayServices somehow ?

Comment: @AlexVPerl: Not legally. Play Services is distributed by Google, not developers.

Comment: No I meant as in use a lower version of play services library as dependency.

Comment: @AlexVPerl: As I wrote in my answer, "While you are welcome to use some older version of that `play-services-maps` dependency, there is no guarantee that ~1.5 billion devices will all support that particular version of the Play Services engine without any updates". Moreover, some of your *other* Play Services dependencies will also want the newer engine, so you would have to downgrade all of them, presumably.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not looking for a 100% solution in this case - having it work on majority of devices will suffice.

Comment: @AlexVPerl: It already does work on the majority of devices. Google does not release a new edition of the Play Services SDK until Play Services is updated on the vast majority of devices.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case. It seems the version I'm using is very recent (pl see dependencies). It just came out it seems. I found this in Google's ref docs, it includes all releases and dates: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions

Comment: @AlexVPerl: "It seems the version I'm using is very recent" -- the Play Service SDK update has been out for [just under a month](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/theres-lot-to-explore-with-google-play.html). Now, you happen to have a device that is not automatically updating Play Services, for whatever reason. That is not especially common. Moreover, that is not something that you can fix, as a developer or as a user. And, it is not like that problem magically goes away just because you try using an older Play Services SDK, as those devices may not have *that* version either.

Comment: Right I get that. But the chance of it occurring is considerably lower with an older release.

Comment: So I have interesting findings to report. After doing a signed build, deploying to the Alpha channel and downloading via Google Play - this warning did not show up. So I'm left under the impression that the warning occurs only during debug builds, or by omitting '@integer/google_play_services_version' in the manifest.